# How do I prevent people from accessing phpmyadmin?

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

I am trying to prevent people from entering /phpmyadmin after my website hostname to access phpmyadmin. I saw that people said to modify apache.conf, but I cannot find that file. I am hosting with xampp, is it the same as httpd.conf? If so What in the file do I have to change. If it is not the same could you enlighten me in simpler terms how I can do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Also I would like to make it a little more secure, so any other advice in this field would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to add an IP filter in an **.htaccess** file to achieve what you want. The only IP allowed to access phpmyadmin will be yours.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?phpmyadmin
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^Your_IP_Here$
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

In the above directives, the third one may be replaced by some other status code or redirection, that's up to you.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but do I put my ip in as !^123.123.23.23$ or do I replace everything such as just 123.123.23.23? Not sure if that question makes sense but I hope it does.

Comment: It did not work. Here is what i did: I created a file .htaccess on my server in the htdocs folder. I then edited the file in sublime, and saved it. However I could still access it from my phone over LTE. Do you know what i did wrong? Was I not supposed to use my routers public ip?

Comment: Maybe your apache.conf (or httpd.conf or some virtualhost.conf) has the **AllowOverride None** directive set on your htdocs directory, it should set to **AllowOverride All**.

Comment: It is set to allow override all

Comment: Any other ideas?